# format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=] scanf ("%1f", &n);

Tags: c

So here's the part of my code I'm having trouble with.
The error says %f is for floats and n is a double, which I've seen in lots of other questions, but the answer was to put in a %1f instead and it still gives back the same error when I try to compile.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main()
    {

      //declaring variables
      double n, new_guess, guess;

      //getting data from the user
      printf ("Enter a number: ");
      scanf ("%1f", &n);
```

Comment: Should be `%lf`, not `%1f`. `l` for long.

Comment: oh my goodness thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Use `%lf` instead of `℅1f` for double data type, because `scanf` will think you are passing a pointer to a float which is a smaller size than a double, and it will return an incorrect value.,